# I passed the file object but still getting parse error with slate3k

Tags: python, python-3.x, slate

I am trying to read the text data of pdf file using "slate3k" . It seems fine to me. But I am getting parse error

I have been using "python3.7" .

```
import slate3k

with open("/home/am-it/Desktop/PythonLearning/pdf_practice/invoice-1.pdf","rb")as file:
    doc = slate3k.PDF(file)
    print(doc)
```

The Output of above code should be text from pdf. but the actual output is

```
 "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/am-it/Desktop/PythonLearning/pdf_practice/invoslate.py", line 4, in <module>
    doc = slate3k.PDF(file)
  File "/home/administrator/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/slate3k/classes.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.doc = PDFDocument()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parser'"
```

I have passed the proper file object but still getting error. So please enlighten me

Comment: It looks like there is probably a bug in slate3k and/or you are using an incompatible version of pdfminer.

Comment: Thanks @Iguananaut....I uninstalled pdfminer.six...It started working

Answer (score 0):

Mine works well with single quotes and with print not indented

```py
import slate3k as slt
with open('pdfPythonTest.pdf','rb') as f:
    extracted_text=slt.PDF(f)
print(extracted_text)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Dude,
in this part of the code:
with open("/home/am-it/Desktop/PythonLearning/pdf_practice/invoice-1.pdf","rb")as file:

you have to write the name of the file plus the extension and not the path.
So, try this:
with open("invoice-1.pdf","rb")as file:

Comment: That's not correct. You can include a path as well as the file name and extension. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open